# Why can't I checkout with subversion 1.7 on a mounted cifs share?

Tags: 12.04, mount, svn, cifs

I have mounted a share on my Ubuntu machine.  I am unable to checkout a subversion working copy onto this share.  When I try to do so, I get an error message:

```
svn: E200033: database is locked, executing statement 'CREATE TABLE REPOSITORY...
```

However,
1) I am able to check out the same repository in a local directory.
2) My colleague on a mac is able to check the repository to the shared directory.

Here are my specs:
Ubuntu 12.04
svn 1.7.5
mount.cifs version: 5.1

```
//scorpio-dev/iemav_dev$    /home/selah/Shares/iemav_dev        cifs noauto,credentials=/etc/cifspw,uid=1000,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the NOBRL option when mounting the CIFS share.  Apparently this is a problem with apps that use SQLite - SVN 1.7 and Firefox come to mind.

[Here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) is the reference for NOBRL

NOBRL - Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is necessary for certain applications that break with cifs style mandatory byte range locks (and most cifs servers do not yet support requesting advisory byte range locks).

Comment: I tried this and now my WC is hosed, it's giving `svn: E200030: sqlite: database disk image is malformed`